# GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment for Credit Card

Tags: paypal

Will GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment  work  if customers use their credit cards instead of Paypal account when paying via Paypal.com checkout page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these API calls will work even if the buyer uses their credit cards instead of paying with their PayPal account.  The Express Checkout flow supports paying with both a PayPal account or a credit card.

Comment: When the funding source is a credit card, is the DoExpressCheckoutPayment still synchronous (e.g., transaction fully completed), or can the transaction be stopped due to fraud and generate an IPN event?

Comment: If the buyer uses a credit card, the payment will be instant.  However, the payment can be placed under review by PayPal or depending on your account settings.  Just as it is still possible to have the funds placed on hold if a chargeback is filed later down the road.  However, if a chargeback is filed, IPN will update your system in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding and clarifying, @PP_MTS_Chad.